# TCPDF + TinyMCE + new <strong> font

Tags: php, tinymce, tcpdf

I would like to generate a PDF file with TCPDF. The content is generated with TinyMCE. I am using additional fonts I downloaded from [fontsquirrel.com](http://fontsquirrel.com). So far so good.

When I select a font in TinyMCE then select the 'BOLD' option, the editor shows me the correct layout, but when the PDF is generated, the regular variant is used.

How can I solve this?

I added the fonts:

```
$pdf->addTTFfont(K_PATH_FONTS.'/Amaranth-Bold-webfont.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->addTTFfont(K_PATH_FONTS.'/Amaranth-webfont.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->addTTFfont(K_PATH_FONTS.'/Amaranth-Italic-webfont.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->addTTFfont(K_PATH_FONTS.'/Amaranth-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

And this is the HTML from TinyMCE:

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <span style="font-family: Amaranth-webfont; font-size: 36px;" data-mce-style="font-family: Amaranth-webfont; font-size: 36px;">Example text</span>
  </strong>
</p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this with a pinch of salt because I have not worked with TCPDF for a couple of years.

I seem to remember that the naming convention of the fonts is very important.

Amaranth-Bold-webfont.ttf  standard
Amaranth-Bold-webfontb.ttf  bold
Amaranth-Bold-webfonti.ttf  italic
Amaranth-Bold-webfontib.ttf  bold italic

Hope that is useful.

Comment: Thanks! I renamed the fonts and it worked. Only Bold Italic is the other way around. I added them like this: Amaranth-webfontb.ttf, Amaranth-webfontbi.ttf and Amaranth-webfonti.ttf